# Beamer: set sep parameter of beamercolorbox globally

Tags: beamer

I have a `beamercolorbox` called "quotationbox" which I use in the following way, setting a `sep` parameter of `4pt`:

```
\begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=4pt]{quotationbox}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\end{beamercolorbox}
```

My question is: Is there a way to set the `sep` parameter globally (i.e., in the preamble) for all `beamercolorbox`es of type "quotationbox"? I am thinking of something analogous to setting the color of the box with `\setbeamercolor{quotationbox}{bg=olive!30}`. I am assuming that there is such a way, but I cannot find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a custom environment:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercolor{quotationbox}{bg=olive!30}

\newenvironment{quotationbox}{%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=4pt]{quotationbox}
}{\end{beamercolorbox}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
    \begin{quotationbox}
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    \end{quotationbox}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]